# In VsCode-Insiders-1.79.0, when I use code snippets, I can't use Tab to accept suggestions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I can accept suggestions in code snippets normally in the stable version of VS Code, but not in Insiders version.
I think it's because the option `editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions` has been removed. How can I solve this issue?

[issue gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSXka.gif)

[What I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQrGu.gif)

Issue on GitHub https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/183411

Comment: What is your `Editor: Suggest Selection Mode`  set to?  Try `always`.  It is a little hard to see in the gif but it llooks like nothing is selected in the second suggestions box, so `tab` won't do anything without a selection.

Comment: Yes, my Editor › Suggest: Selection Mode setting is always.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to your claim, `editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions` has not been removed in VS Code 1.79. [Its default value has just been changed from `true` to `false`](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_79#_quick-suggestions-and-snippets). According to [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/183411#issuecomment-1563134520) by [@jrieken](https://github.com/jrieken) in [the GitHub issue ticket I assume you created](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/183411), this change was made on purpose (see [Suggestions box's first choice is sometimes selected, sometimes NOT #173387](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173387) and the linked issue tickets for some history on this), and starting from 1.79, you are supposed to use the <kbd>enter</kbd> key to accept suggestions inside snippet contexts.

---

I wonder if you could work around the issue by binding the keyboard shortcut to go to the next snippet placeholder to something other than <kbd>tab</kbd>. Maybe something like this?:

```json
{
    "key": "tab",
    "command": "-jumpToNextSnippetPlaceholder",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && hasNextTabstop && inSnippetMode"
},
{
    "key": "", // TODO pick something else
    "command": "-jumpToNextSnippetPlaceholder",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && hasNextTabstop && inSnippetMode"
},
{
    "key": "tab",
    "command": "acceptSelectedSuggestion",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && hasNextTabstop && inSnippetMode"
},
```

Comment: But I'm still used to using only the Tab key to do these things. Thank you for your suggestion. I think if it's still the same in the stable version of vscode, more people will pay attention to this matter, and there should be a better solution by then. Thank you again. ❤