# Vscode Auto-completion is annoying

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete

So I know that this question is weird, but it reduces my productivity a lot and I'm not super happy about it.

So Vscode's autocompletion is nice and all, but It does have a weird case.

Let's say I'm writing a div in reactjs, and I want to have a className property in it, I just need to type class and the autocompletion will fill for me className, sounds good and all but then I can not use my autocompletion anymore at that point,since when you press tab it will direct you to the end of className ( like className=""|, the | is my cursor) and when I haven't tabbed it yet, the autocompletion when I am in the quote of className won't work unless I press Esc so that it quits out the directing cursor or anything you call it like that.

Comment: you can enable autocomplete inside a string with a setting, you can also press Ctrl+Space to force autocompletion

Comment: Now that's the point, Using ctrl+space is a waste of time like using Esc. I Just want it to be "auto"" though.

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. possibly related for 1.79: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76335930/11107541